# HTML and AngularJS Interpolation for email form

Tags: html, angularjs, email

I'm using formspree.io for some simple contact forms and want to dynamically change the email address with Angular1 so it looks something like this:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/{{ user.email }}" method="POST">
```

Can anyone help shine some light on this? I can't quite work it out so any thoughts would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the following link. it has clearly mensioned how to post a form in angular, jquery, etc.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

go to the [formspree](https://formspree.io/) website. there you can see the clear explanation in traditional way

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="email" name="_replyto">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

just convert this form into angular supported form and your work will be pretty easy if you use twoway data binding

ng-submit also works well [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

here submit() is a function that trigger the post request

Comment: you can even use ng-submit and do the same here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 0):

Trust the url input with SCE (Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)

See [sce docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)